# Custom UIPicker control IOS

Tags: ios, uipickerview

im looking for a similar control to this [Android Wheel](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/), its very similar to UIPickerView, but i know that Apple use to reject APPs that modify UIPickerView appearance.

I need a control that let me put images on a infinite loop scroll and let the user drag to select one.

I've found some controls [here](http://code4app.net/category/picker), but most of them only support strings, some support images and are looped but dont let the user scroll.

My purpose is to make a button scroll loop where you can drag any button to the center of the wheel and see a text description on a uilabel, i dont need the buttons to be clickables.

I hope I explained well, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: To me that Android control looks exactly like a UIPickerView. To achieve infinite (alike) scrolling, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618816/uipickerview-infinite-rows

Comment: I have made a custom UIPickerView by extending UIView. I need 7-8 hours to get that code. Is that fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would better suggest you to go with the `iCarousel` [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). This enables you a different mode of scrolling & directions & effects which you can project on a Custom view similar (by Sliding-In & Sliding-Out from the bottom of screen) like a `UIPickerView`. This is not at all made using extending UIPickerView, but you can project it like that. Once you see a demo app of it, you can eventually change your mind to use this over custom UIPickerView.

Just implement the delegate method declared [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel#protocols) to know which of the element was clicked. `iCarousel` comes with a image loading view also. You can look into that too.

But if you want to stick with `UIPickerView` customization, then please have a look at this [stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504686/customize-uipicker-insert-images) post. This is certainly what you want, except that you need to add button instead of images.

Comment: iCarousel looks really good, can i make the scroll loop with it?

Comment: I have used it for circular looping, but you can try other options of it for vertical direction with really large range of numbers. Or else if you think your list will be infinite then provide an option for custom input from user to enter a value in that format & then you can append that value to the existing list & I carousel will add new item to the list.

Comment: OK, i found it just return yes to iCarouselOptionWrap on the delegate method, really thanks, just what i was looking for